# Powershell ADUser command not syncing with AD

Tags: powershell

The text below is my attempt to use the Import-Module ActiveDirectory

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Get-Command New-ADUser -Syntax

$firstName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the first name"
$lastName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the last name"


$UserParams = @{
    Name = "$firstName $lastName"
    GivenName = $firstName
    Surname = $lastName 
    UserPrincipalName = "$firstName.lastname"
    EmailAddress = "$firstName.$lastName@<domain>"
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = 1 
    Enabled = 1 
    StreetAddress = "<info>" 
    Office = "<info>" 
    State = "<info>" 
    PostalCode = "<info>" 
    Country = "<info>" 
    Path = "OU=External,OU=Workers,OU=Group,DC=<domain>,DC=com" 
}
New-ADUser @UserParams
```

When this is ran I get this error

```
+ New-ADUser @UserParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=test user,OU...=<domain>,DC=com:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:<port>,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Is the path incorrect? I know it should be correct because I have copied it from distinguishedName in String Attribute Editor.

Comment: You missed a `$` in  `"$firstName.lastname"`. Also, better not concatenate like that with a dot in between.  $firstName is a string and doesn't have a property called lastname.. Use something like  `'{0}.{1}' -f $firstName, $lastName` instead. Also, **never** trust user input from Read-Host. Could be an empty string in there..

Comment: In addition to Theo's comment, the syntax for the UPN is wrong.

Comment: And `ChangePasswordAtLogon` and `Enabled` are of type Boolean, not Int